# Is it possible to prevent zend engine to free resources?

Tags: php, resources, php-internals

Is it possible to prevent zend engine to free resources allocated in PHP?

For example, when a process is forked() and the resource is duplicated to the child process, when either child process or parent process exit, the resource is free thus other processes can't access them any more.

Comment: Or it doesn't free resources automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Freeing resourses is not the problem, because the parent and child have no access to each other's resourses. Maybe you are talking about mysql connection. The problem is that even if you don't call `mysql_close()` it's called by php. This is an example

```
mysql_connect(...); 
if(pcntl_fork()) exit();
mysql_query( ... ); //no mysql connection here
```

I heard that parent can prevent this by killing itself with `SIGKILL`, but I haven't tested it. Should be something like:

```
mysql_connect(...); 
if(pcntl_fork()) {
  posix_kill ( posix_getpid() , SIGKILL);
  exit(); // won't hurt to leave it here
}
mysql_query( ... ); //no mysql connection here
```

Or if parent starts many children and they close connection to database on quit you can use the same approach on children.